# Calculate the percentages of a column in a data frame - "grouped" by column

Tags: r, dataframe

I am an R beginner and came to the point, where I need the possibility to calculate percentages of values in a data frame, but "grouped" by an other column value, quite often.

I have a data frame with around 1000 rows, containing mediatype, version, collection (= year) and count (for this year). I can filter them, to get only a specific mediatye:

```
trSpdf <- trS[trS$Mediatype == 'application/pdf',]
```

and get the following exemplary output:

```
> trSpdf 

        Mediatype Version Collection      Count
39 application/pdf      -1     co2008         2.0
40 application/pdf      -1     co2009         5.0
43 application/pdf       1     co2008         1.0
44 application/pdf       1     co2009         1.0
48 application/pdf     1.1     co2008        16.0
52 application/pdf     1.2     co2008        20.0
53 application/pdf     1.2     co2009        90.0
... (continuing) ...
```

What I want, is to calculate the percentage of each version for each collection (= year) compared to all versions in this collection, so for this example the result should be:

```
5.12% of all versions in co2008 were version -1 (2.0 / total sum for co2008)
2.56% of all versions in co2008 were version 1 (1.0 / total sum for co2008)
...
93,75% of all versions in co2009 were version 1.2 (90.0 / total sum for co2009)
...
```

Thanks in advance for any answers on how I could solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use `ave` to add a column giving the total count per `Mediatype` and `Collection`:

```
trS <- transform(trS, Tot.Count = ave(Count, Mediatype, Collection, FUN = sum))
```

Then, it is easy pretty obvious how to compute the percentage:

```
trS <- transform(trS, percentage = 100 * Count/Tot.Count)
```

Or if you want it nicely formatted (e.g. "5.13%") then use `sprintf`:

```
trS <- transform(trS, percentage = paste0(sprintf("%.2f", 100 * Count/Tot.Count),
                                          "%"))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works very well. I was able to produce similar results with the `plyr` package (`ddply(trSpdf, .(Collection), transform, perc = Count/sum(Count)) `), but your solution is much more understandable to me ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following:

```
with(trSpdf, by(Version, Collection, FUN= function(x) round(prop.table(table(x))*100,2)))
```

You could change `FUN` to be whatever you wanted your output to look like.

EDIT: Try this:

```
yearsums <- with(trSpdf, tapply(Count, Collection, sum))
mapply(FUN = function(x,y) x/yearsums[as.character(y)], trSpdf$Count, trSpdf$Collection)
```

I'm sure there is a better way, though.

Comment: thanks, but that does not seem to work. it does not take the `Count` into account, only IF an entry for this year exists, or not. For instance the percentages for Version -1 are 50.00 for co2008 and 50.00 for co2009